# Can't create method to get data from database hibernate mySQL + Spring mvc

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

[my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Sro.png)

I really hope for your help! The situation is this: I'm trying to get the value of my disciplines from the database, these disciplines are related to the semester. In the display page, the user must select the semester he needs, after which he clicks on the selection button and all disciplines associated with this semester should be displayed. But I always get the same error "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists." I am attaching all the code that I wrote to perform this action.

```js
<tr>
    <td style="font-size: large;">Select semester</td>
    <td style="padding-left: 50px">
        <select>
            <c:forEach items="${semestr}" var="semestr">
                <c:url var="chooseButton" value="/chooseSemester">
                    <c:param name="semId" value="${semestr.id}"/>
                </c:url>
                <option value="${semestr.id}">${semestr.name}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </td>
    
    <td style="padding-left: 20px">
        <input type="submit" value="Select" id="button" onclick="window.location.href = 'chooseButton'">
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
@RequestMapping("chooseSemester")
public String chooseSemester(@RequestParam("semId")int semId,Model model){
    List<Discipline> allDisciplines = service.getDisciplineSemestrId(semId);
    model.addAttribute("allDisc", allDisciplines);
    return "semestr";
}
```

```
package com.kushnirmark.spring.project.DAO;

import com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity.Discipline;
import com.kushnirmark.spring.project.entity.Semestr;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class SemestrImpl implements SemestrDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<Semestr> getSemestr() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Semestr> semestrs = session.createQuery("from Semestr", Semestr.class).getResultList();
        return semestrs;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Discipline> getDisciplineSemestr() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Discipline> discSem = session.createQuery("select a.discipline from Discipline a" +
                " inner join Semestr_Disc b on a.id=b.id_discipline where b.id_semestr = 1 ").getResultList();
        return discSem;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Discipline> getDisciplineSemestrId(int semId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<Discipline>query = session.createQuery("select a.discipline from" +
                " Discipline a inner join Semestr_Disc b on a.id=b.id_discipline where b.id_semestr =:semId");
        query.setParameter("semId",semId);
        query.executeUpdate();
        return (List<Discipline>) query;
    }


    @Override
    public void saveNewSemester(Semestr semestr) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(semestr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of `getDisciplineSemestrId` in SemestrImpl looks fishy. You create select query, but then execute update on it, and return the query itself cast to List.

Try this:

```
    @Override
    public List<Discipline> getDisciplineSemestrId(int semId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<Discipline>query = session.createQuery("select a.discipline from" +
                " Discipline a inner join Semestr_Disc b on a.id=b.id_discipline where b.id_semestr =:semId");
        query.setParameter("semId",semId);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

`Query` getResultList() executes a select query and returns the result, while executeUpdate() executes update or delete statements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! This is more logical than what I wrote :) but unfortunately the error has not disappeared anywhere, maybe I have a problem not only in the database query, something in the controllers is unwritten wrong? I have doubts about writing jstl code, since I wrote everything intuitively. I'll wait for an answer, thanks again for the answer !!!

Comment: I found why there was a display error, I did not take the name of the button for processing into the ${} form. Now, when I click on the select button, the method works correctly for me, but it does not see the semester id, I probably do not get it correctly. When working out the method, id is replaced by '?' , tell me by jstl what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MarkKush With the current configuration of `chooseSemester` method, the request to the backend should look like that - `/chooseSemester?semId=0`. Are you sending the semester id like that?

Comment: @RequestParam("semId")int semId using this parameter I am trying to pass the semester id value to the method parameter and when I click on the '${chooseButton}' button, I follow the link in order to pass all this to the method. Maybe I'm not extracting the id correctly?? I'm just very bad at jstl .... that's why I ask for your help))

Comment: Can you check if you are sending correct request? You can see requests in the developer tools of your browser, network tab. That way you can see if looking for error in the jstl is correct direction, or it's something else entirely.

Comment: In the developer tools I get this information, I don’t quite understand what it means, but it sounds like this:  
One or more documents in this page is in Quirks Mode, which will render the affected document(s) with quirks incompatible with the current HTML and CSS specifications.
Quirks Mode exists mostly due to historical reasons. If this is not intentional, you can add or modify the DOCTYPE to be `<!DOCTYPE html>` to render the page in No Quirks Mode.

Comment: And another message : 
A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown.

Comment: Maybe you should update the question with latest data, so more people can see.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to figure out the solution to this problem, they helped me to add the controller in this topic, after writing it, getting data from the database works correctly, it looks like this:

```
@Override
public List<Discipline> getDisciplineSemestrId(int id) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query<Discipline>query = session.createQuery("select a.discipline from" +
            " Discipline a inner join Semestr_Disc b on a.id=b.id_discipline where b.id_semestr =:semId");
    query.setParameter("semId",id);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

There was also a problem with getting data from a jsp page, the correct code for getting it now looks like this:

```html
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/allSemestrsSem" method="get">
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size: large;">Select semester</td>
        <td style="padding-left: 50px">
            <select name="selectSemestr">
                <c:forEach items="${semestr}" var="semestr">
                    <option value="${semestr.id}">${semestr.name}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td style="padding-left: 20px">
            <security:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
            <input type="submit" id="button" value="select"/>
        </td>
        </security:authorize>
    </tr>
</form>
```

There was a lack of proper wrapping, but now everything works as it should. I hope that the solution of my problem can also be useful for someone, I've been trying to figure it out for 10 days and now everything works

This is what my controller looks like:

```html
    @RequestMapping(value = "/allSemestrsSem" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String allSemestrs(@RequestParam(name = "selectSemestr")String selectSemestr, Model model) {
        List<Semestr> semestr = service.getSemestr();
        model.addAttribute("semestr", semestr);
        List<Discipline> allDisciplines = service.getDisciplineSemestrId(Integer.valueOf(selectSemestr));
        model.addAttribute("allDisc", allDisciplines);
        return "semestr";
    }
```